# SQL Server search in nvarchar & ntext

Tags: search, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 as my database engine in a VS2010, C# ASP.NET web app. My project is Farsi (Persian) so I've used `nvarchar` and `ntext` as my data types.

I use following query to find rows from my database but nothing is returned, while I have a row with the specified keyword. Of course my keyword is in Persian (unicode).

What is going wrong here? Is it because of using Farsi language? How can I search in `nvarchar` and `ntext` columns containing unicode characters?

```
myCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tblArticle where name LIKE '%" + txtSearch.Text + "%'", SQLConnection);
```

Comment: `NTEXT` is deprecated - **don't** use it for new projects! Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead - that makes searching that much easier, too!

Comment: Also: you should use **parametrized queries** instead of concatenating together your SQL command! That approach is highly vulnerable to **SQL injection attacks** - don't use it.

Comment: thanks marc, but this search is being done in an nvarchar field, and I get no result! while I can easily see that exact value in my database, what is happening here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use the `N'` prefix to indicate that you're searching for a Unicode string:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tblArticle WHERE name LIKE N'%......%'
```

Otherwise, you're converting your search string back to non-Unicode and then searching....

Comment: thanks marc, it solved my problem! You have helped me several times. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You must use `COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2` to get results. Works for Amharic for Ethiopians.

```
Select * From YourTableName where ColNameYouSearch LIKE N'%YourSerchCriteria%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `C#` `ASP.NET`, but using `nvarchar` or `ntext` shouldn't make any difference in query type. I am wandering you are only assigning your query command to a variable and not executing it.. 
should you do something like `myCommand.execute()` ?